# Receiving error when installing gcutil

Tags: google-compute-engine, gcutil

When I try to install gcutil using this guide : https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/gcutil/

I receive this error (using install.bat) :

```
(gcloud.components.update) Your current working directory is inside the Cloud SD
K install root: C:\gcutil\google-cloud-sdk.  In order to perform this update, ru
n the command from outside of this directory.
```

What is the cause of this ? What is the working directory being referred to ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's referring to the directory your shell is currently in. Running:

```
cd C:\gcutil
```

should get you in the right place to run the batch file.

Comment: do you mean copy the installation files to a new dir "C:\gcutil" and run from there ? Should "C:\gcutil" already exist ?

Comment: Are you running install.bat from the command line, or by double-clicking on it?

Comment: When running from the command line, make sure you're in the parent directory of the sdk. For example, if your current directory is: C:\gcutil\google-cloud-sdk  (as the error message indicates). Run: cd ..    Then run: google-cloud-sdk\install.bat